# Query to find out same product Factor id with different values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query to help me fetch out the products which have same factor id(column X) with different values(another Y) within the same table. For examples factor 12 for rows A, B, c should have same values(column X) throughout. If the factor is 10, then the value will also be different.

I tried a query but that only get me a result when you join 2 tables

Comment: Please show sample input and expected outcome as tables instead of describing it only.

Comment: Consider the output for columns X and Y  where row A,B and C from column X have values 12,12 and 12 respectively. 
Now my question!
The column X suppose will have different ID’s like 12, 10, 10, 8 so column Y is supposed to have values same for both ID 10 and different for 12 and 8 respectively. So now these two columns X and Y are in a same table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Answer (score 0):

> I need a query to help me fetch out the products which have same factor id(column X) with different values(another Y) within the same table.

You can use an analytic function to `COUNT` the `DISTINCT` `y` values for each `x` and then filter in an outer query to show only those rows with multiple `y` values:

```sql
SELECT x, y
FROM   (
  SELECT x,
         y,
         COUNT(DISTINCT y) OVER (PARTITION BY x) AS num_y
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_y > 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (x, y) AS
SELECT 12, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'D' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | A |
| 12 | B |
| 12 | C |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fVjOnfRB)